# Setting the discriminator dynamically in Doctrine2

Tags: inheritance, doctrine-orm, discriminator

I have a `Parent` entity with 2 child entities (`Foo` and `Bar`) implementing `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance.

Is it possible to create a `new Parent()` entity and dynamically set it's discriminator to `foo` instead of creating a `new Foo()` ?

Comment: No, it's not possible, at least without ugly hacks. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have a scenario where I get a string representing the discriminator, and I need to create an entity of that type. I've created a method for that, just wanted to know if there is a better way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't, if you really need the scenario mentioned in your comment, then you'll probably be better with some kind of factory method:

```php
abstract class MyParent
{
    public static function fromString($type)
    {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'foo':
                return new Foo();
            case 'bar':
                return new Bar();
        }
        throw new DomainException('Unknown type: ' . $type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) btw, why did you declare the class abstract?

Comment: Just because I assumed that only the subclasses would be instantiated. But if the parent class can be instantiated as well, then you can remove the `abstract` keyword!